# #GP on some ISRs, APIC and PIT not sending IRQs

Tags: x86-64, osdev, apic

I've been working on code to test the speed of the APIC using the PIT. There are several problems I can't figure out. First, when testing my ISRs for the two timers, I get general protection faults on the iretq instructions. Second, neither timer actually fires any interrupts. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

[Link to the relevant file.](https://gitlab.com/selfReferentialName/osmkvii/blob/master/boot/uefi-amd64/apic.asm)

Comment: Probably not what your problem is, but this looks suspicious:  `pop rdx`
 `pop rax`
 `mov rax, ckpoint`
 `call print` `iretq` . You seem to restore RAX and RDX but then you clobber RAX with `ckpoint` and then call `printf`. Seems like at a minimum you have trashed RAX, not sure what `printf` trashes before returning with `iretq` . Is that what you intended?

Comment: It's code that tests to see where it gets. The #GP occurs regardless of whether the checkpointing is there or not. ckpoint is printed however, which is how I know that it faults on the iretq.

Comment: I would help if you commented your code more: I don't remember all the APIC registers by offsets and it's not clear to me what are you timing.

Answer (score 1):

The general protection faults were caused by having an invalid CS register due to not reloading the CS register after loading the GDT. It's not in the code I linked to at all.